# Method in Class Instance not changing variables?

Tags: java, class, scope, lwjgl

I have two classes: Main and Unit. The Unit class is initialized as such, with the variables `x` and `y` declared at the top of the class:

```
public Unit(int health, int damage, int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        Main.drawQuad(x, y, 15, 15);
    }
```

I have a method that takes the `x` or `y` variables and adds 1 to them. To my understanding, this would make it move (Main.drawQuad is a method to simply draw a quad, but shortened). Instead, it does nothing, and `x` and `y` are never changed.

Do I need to declare them differently? Access them differently? I have tried different variable scopes. Must I change them via the Main class? I am working with LWJGL.

Comment: We need to see your code where you change the variables. And I really think that if you can't figure this out, then you shouldn't be trying to make games yet. No offense.

Comment: Java is pass by value.

Comment: @opiop65, I've never struck an issue such as this before. I am not properly educated, for one, and I've not done too much with LWJGL.

Comment: And all it is right now, for purposes of trying to get it to work, is "x += 5;".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That method does not make it move. It's your job to 'make it move'. You have to redraw your quad each time by incrementing `x` and `y` values, then calling the drawing API again.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I was under the assumption that because the instance was created in the render method, which is called in the update loop, it would adjust.

Comment: @IHazABone You are very welcome. Try putting the `drawQuad` in a *for-loop* where you increment `x` and `y` on each iteration, and call `drawQuad` each time. See what happens. :-)

Comment: What happens is it draws an entirely new quad without erasing the previous/: I remember this happening once before, but I do not recall how to fix it or what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You need to call glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER) before you render each frame.

Comment: That line (more specifically: `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` is called at the top of the render method. Should I call it in the Unit class?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things could be wrong, you haven't really shown the code that could be going wrong.

- Perhaps you only think you are changing x and y.
- Maybe you don't redraw the quad with the new values.
- Maybe you are changing x and y in the wrong object.

Your best bet will be to step through the code with a debugger and pay close attention to what the values are, when they change, what object they are in, and what happens with those values afterwards.

Comment: I had not realized that I had to redraw the quad from within the unit class. I was doing that only in the main class. Thank you.